# Remove something from a place to another place (Grammatically correct?)

Tags: grammaticality

Remove already has the definition of taking something away from somewhere so I am not sure if it will be redundant to say "from a place...to another place".
Can you please help?
Thanks!

Comment: Remove refers only to taking away.  You don't remove something to somewhere else.  "Transfer" or "move" would be better words for that.

Comment: you can also use "to relocate"

Comment: @fixer1234 [Since when?](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22remove%20it%20to%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1811&lr=lang_en)

Comment: @tchrist, OED (apparently Britishism): "dated", if that's what you're referring to.  Also, all examples listed were simply "remove to", not remove from one place to another.

Comment: "He removed it from the room" is certainly totally idiomatic, and shows that 'remove something from' is synonymous with 'take something out of' etc. The dictionary definition suggested is inadequate to cover this usage precisely. [AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/remove) has << To move [something] from a place or position occupied: _removed the cups from the table_. >> which, if precision were observed, would necessitate the example << _removed the cups the table._ >>

Comment: AHD also licenses directionality: << To transfer or convey from one place to another: _removed the family to Texas_. >>

Answer (score -2):

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/remove?q=Remove

to take something or someone away from somewhere, or off something.

You would, therefore, have to say something like: I removed it from this place and put it in that place.

You can't say: I removed it to that place.
You could say: I moved it to that place.

Comment: [This answer is demonstrably inaccurate](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22remove%20it%20to%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1811&lr=lang_en) — and historically wrong. I recommend you consult the actual OED, as I trust that the historical record elaborated there will surprise you.